# Error: New Project keeps being in language Kotlin

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I just downloaded Android Studio Flamingo 2 days ago and I found it strange that there is no longer an option to select languages on the new project screen when I create a new project anymore. When I create one, the language is always Kotlin, and I can't change it.

I tried to do it again and again everytime but the language keeps being in Kotlin. I wonder if I did anything wrong? Does anybody knows about this?

[image]

Comment: You're creating a project that uses Jetpack Compose, which is Kotlin based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create a project with Jetpack Compose, which does not support Java at all. Of course, my personal recommendation is not to use Java for new projects, as Google recommends, but if you wish, you can always choose Basic Views Activity or Empty Views Activity template in Create Project wizard. There you can still choose between Kotlin and Java